# links.append() does not show all the image links as a list

Tags: html, image, image-processing, web-scraping, web-crawler

I need to scrape 29 images of this hotel. With the code below, the output is each link separately every time I run the cell. Even though I used links.append(), I need to re-run the cell in order to get another image.

```
r = rq.get("https://uk.hotels.com/ho177101/?q-check-out=2020-04-18&FPQ=3&q-check-in=2020-04-17&WOE=6&WOD=5&q-room-0-children=0&pa=1&tab=description&JHR=2&q-room-0-adults=2&YGF=2&MGT=1&ZSX=0&SYE=3#:WO")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

links = []

x = soup.select('img[src^="https://exp.cdn-hotels.com/hotels/1000000/560000/558400/558353"]')

for img in x:
    links.append(img['src'])

#os.mkdir("hotel_photos")

for l in links: 
    print(l)
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
links = []

x = soup.select('a[href^="https://exp.cdn-hotels.com/hotels/1000000/560000/558400/558353"]')

for img in x:
    links.append(img['href'])
```

But, this will only work for that specific link, if you need a code that would scrape any link you provide, because this "https://exp.cdn-hotels.com/hotels/1000000/560000/558400/558353" changes depending on the hotel, so this would be a better approach:

```
x = soup.select("li[id^='thumb-']")
for i in x:
    links.append((next(i.children, None)["href"]))

for l in links: 
    print(l)
```

PS: If you need after that to download the pictures, make sure to replace "&w=82&h=82" with "&w=773&h=530" to match the picture displayed.

Comment: I just edited it, so that you can pass any link, and still be able to scrap it without any problem.